# Как узнать, что пользователь достиг этих элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

В теории это дело должно менять содержимое #title на название болка, который сейчас в поле зрения. Но ничего не происходит. В консоли никаких ошибок нет, но со своей задачей код совершенно не справляется. Знаю, что тут полно костылей, пока по-другому не умею.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
        
  /* elements */
        
  var $introducion = $("#introducion"),
  $photo = $("#photo"),
  $projects = $("#projects"),
  $news = $("#news"),
     
  /* elements positions */
        
  $introducionPos = $introducion.offset().tot,
  $photoPos = $photo.offset().tot,
  $projectsPos = $projects.offset().tot,
  $newsPos = $news.offset().tot,
      
  /* window heignt */
        
  $winHeight = $(window).height(),
        
  /* distances to elements */
        
  $scrollToIntroducion = $introducionPos - $winHeight,
  $scrollToPhoto = $photoPos - $winHeight,
  $scrollToProjects = $projectsPos - $winHeight,
  $scrollToNews = $newsPos - $winHeight;
       
  /* checking */
        
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var $winScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if($winScrollTop > $scrollToIntroducion){
      $("#title").text("Introducion");
    }
    else if($winScrollTop > $scrollToPhoto){
      $("#title").text("Galery");
    }
    else if($winScrollTop > $scrollToProjects){
      $("#title").text("Projects");
    }
    else if($winScrollTop > $scrollToNews){
      $("#title").text("News");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width">   
<title>My site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<header class="logo">
   <ul>
    <li id="logoc">
        <h1 id="logo"></h1>
    </li>
    <li id="name">
        <h1 id="title"></h1>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://galactikka.com/146568">
            <img src="galactikka.svg" alt="">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="https://vk.com/dm1tr1y147">
        <i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ourwildworldpictures/">
            <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://ficbook.net/authors/2549589">
            <img src="ficbook.svg" alt="">
        </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</header>

<!-- 
    INTRODUCION
 -->

<section id="introducion">
    <p>Hello! Glad to see you on my <span>site</span><br>My name is <span>Dmitriy</span> I'm <script type="text/javascript">var date = new Date(); document.write(date.getFullYear()-2003);</script><br>My hobbies are <span>photographing</span>, <span>programming</span> and <span>writing</span></p>
</section>

<!-- 
    GALERY
 -->

<a href='' id='more'><i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left' aria-hidden='true'></i> More</a>
<section id="photo">
    <div id="exp">
        <img id="first" class="galery" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2b8I_zX4FGxIZ8pchP9cvKf58E2ef8qmdB1EnQOVdPP4Y-dSf3XkEYLwj7vcGE5W6XVyxRZrLu6EDJqvQ1sJHWZMJiu6J8WfjUXWoNaRual_kUJaX3pKgYoezfKRTDBw6gFhHm2bfOVvVWfj92_CVi9XMpEF_c8fxThyk-Kv3nsiYEpp0s_QSHmE5N8LmrRlaFQe4xaCOqtULajJKSVjjpRXnQjaTNnH2GvxiCMq6bhmjXqgIi-U9gSQ9lM_fBB1tT-FSuwt5ftpI3WLaXIArWJ6kBELJy_qtlQR7yyqrKr91jOeCF0ap7p5iuLT999qg-6BxaEdyTfG3eia2wIK-6JUZBtSUClqF4FUcRYRqZWXX7ieaLT7e4LNK0a_nFjAx9NQdIQC7x7uGPmEx8ZvxPXPiaPK6DbhIw4y1TdPpkskcU0oLFpZjHmdZnWi4wnjPZp2dZCYa0MZ-3xnjvm21aDnF-n-JeDPYJR-8a_XZQ_R-PeoeWTU08TM7cWvoyeXWOXHWotAbVA3MRpJl2h21KgSsxN-mqT3bSuRLXqgiazqb0ubQOz4_S_N9pW3Ex3pxbhAVRZKF3H_FgcJiKaUO089-P00_qA29RK86nRHEg=w1001-h750-no" alt="">
        <img id="second" class="galery" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Xk-USyHTClr2hYM0NOhcw2z1AMR7GHBreZYqVXDBv-BugFrjNjh6cv3ixTyrSv9xK0NzpD6-a56RRNowl9ImZPwYyTgLIGvc83kdKyWdhAu9D99BnRjBw5KtlRnfEsSxwk2qU1LHk-EYD5pKvs7bLZ7oYqRUZ2pyMX-kWbPxyoKDe2a8rtI0VKgmMBRlef-BQxlQ40AfCzdFTltPmV7-fNXQinXUgbD4vmve3lGxOnd-HFqr3_D9PVYo1r1Cszohw2m16kQ52AFFbNB-TPphuiMy0QHnOLoDipKkskpr-CVSosieVltVhEuFSgxvLNK7wjt_s7G5EpA9unnHnhgqpQeLs-WdQsjfpjSH-4pcxCPkN9yq9_DnDCx7-bc37_wdLNc630cnQ4YSLNk3b--d_bQbdtiVaGBFe-CdQvU5M_ZaglpJ_fvIGrGltntnDdrG5mnDqDSHVGOOwHuOIkuW1NWL6HmHmUJ1TqJWlFcJDNR0ZLOq_hcO7j3iQwdxlfLDzY0lKYHoFAfoJ7sRqP95QVsb3cUFLW_dsftehexvQqyhKouYzy-lELPKUEz82Fj8wW3nJTwJUxDbWqJh1FFUxcXXEdsFb6xo8NTDoXBCNQ=w753-h750-no" alt="">
        <img id="third" class="galery" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/L5EDRAd8Fck0fd5WDXD4CT5cNjB2piVH8JlDZ9SCdzeavuQZF5icWKyHepu5pNtEGAw9-ErzaTztRMJb2hhVVcpFFaJGTPSTeMpAruxu5Jt9tQ9nWIXM1k8MMQedGaVm3WFNDmreqOzUYb-cqXbr0_sqAk1hGSMmjjhDNm9Pax0Vm4URcQM-4c7V6dchF9xAEDUYr7SBwpF2t8fIW_fTpdmwawPwzTcGM2njZZvqKVd4GNMdhztvBdvNURrkzRRg2RKrSHZlU17xWXAfvCUVy2HVbgBUHe4LEpm9v7IpQCEFHfcJPwl9nfkHyLk5M3YI4RPwkZtTCuJmx6xnQyJp8xDdGHnwOC9AjVEAWPpTXjFcgcWp7qPmsuAEEEUugffhcm0SMSH5xauUioGUmSrZ_H_BsBKhjrc96hidsK1DbSR5IUFS0SL-iU1cErVsrKAAFLAo1ChP772BXof9fPBUU4NIGsEwONyIwe8t37oOXHe4xkiRuEPAvjcYwDsQ8_BXNPVUHMAFMtRfm-EyHoFWk8ZuZxsTsq-LOA_my8MfQKkQthyQx0hIbp1F2g0TLNK6KDS0_5naye-eHjxWkYLPYCfZHELdoSi9WrKjfq94gw=s750-no" alt="">
        <img id="forth" class="galery" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Rg7w2QnYejKWtZd07aCjdaalmkIQVPHXylfQBtOdwxbCDB2Rem3ddiQqGfGuhzVkqHxZyWUbeh5inVWY4KOiZaGLRmR2gvavWDcnO309-x6qY7hoXDTMaSOP99JytCiLcDEp-I-WOhMeCSgQTC5Cw4MMM8dtySKO3hX22D_Me-YERm7MbOi_9b-Wmb_rx0pptmgj4NhXaeiK3c7weE43UtQOV2qVNeoQ6NZEvIolZS4ouO6W62G-EnfcFg6mTNFg_fxI9HbDBaxfUXVfLdGlJKbbP1lN9WtLudq9D8AxId0ob7vByLDG0fDNCVjp8JQAOW90bFitLmeu1SmQVeBKPNC6XMahxjb7Dqjozt3p3vQp8NMqimwlbTskJoiEMydoF-ifkEJVpUtHeH5T2jM6c0DWlSQHqbb5byAlGVC7iZuQk-4KdNIel6dIneGFm7e2LqW9gn1gFGuD0jQQnuCyIdee1dACIBXiMEZixpA1jv7_qdfBkx_AN355hNBPp7RYHk75QnT8oF6HkGqDJNfje4n7rI0zgbyCK70hG8eJPxS-ry_oTj0xmvWSXYUefUZsa53OE5F_NaCtuYfqjkzBkNK3CTyd-cZWYSg2ajo=w1001-h750-no" alt="">
        
        <!-- 
            JQUERY
        -->
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- 
            IMG RESIZER
        -->
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.galery').height($('.galery').width());
                $(window).resize(function(){
                    $('.galery').height($('.galery').width());
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".galery").hover(function() {
                $("#more").css;
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- 
    PROJECTS
 -->

<section id="projects">
    <div class="exs" id="first">
        <h2>Q.Noter</h2>
        <img class="exsi" src="clipboard1.svg" alt="Screenshot">
    </div>
    <div class="exs" id="second">
        <h2>Later</h2>
        <img class="exsi" src="Flag_of_None.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="exs" id="third">
        <h2>Later</h2>
        <img class="exsi" src="Flag_of_None.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <!-- 
        IMG RESIZER
     -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('.exsi').height($('.exsi').width());
                $(window).resize(function(){
                    $('.exsi').height($('.exsi').width());
                });
            });
        </script>
</section>

<!-- 
    NEWS
 -->

<section id="news">
    <div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
        <img class="exni" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2b8I_zX4FGxIZ8pchP9cvKf58E2ef8qmdB1EnQOVdPP4Y-dSf3XkEYLwj7vcGE5W6XVyxRZrLu6EDJqvQ1sJHWZMJiu6J8WfjUXWoNaRual_kUJaX3pKgYoezfKRTDBw6gFhHm2bfOVvVWfj92_CVi9XMpEF_c8fxThyk-Kv3nsiYEpp0s_QSHmE5N8LmrRlaFQe4xaCOqtULajJKSVjjpRXnQjaTNnH2GvxiCMq6bhmjXqgIi-U9gSQ9lM_fBB1tT-FSuwt5ftpI3WLaXIArWJ6kBELJy_qtlQR7yyqrKr91jOeCF0ap7p5iuLT999qg-6BxaEdyTfG3eia2wIK-6JUZBtSUClqF4FUcRYRqZWXX7ieaLT7e4LNK0a_nFjAx9NQdIQC7x7uGPmEx8ZvxPXPiaPK6DbhIw4y1TdPpkskcU0oLFpZjHmdZnWi4wnjPZp2dZCYa0MZ-3xnjvm21aDnF-n-JeDPYJR-8a_XZQ_R-PeoeWTU08TM7cWvoyeXWOXHWotAbVA3MRpJl2h21KgSsxN-mqT3bSuRLXqgiazqb0ubQOz4_S_N9pW3Ex3pxbhAVRZKF3H_FgcJiKaUO089-P00_qA29RK86nRHEg=w1001-h750-no" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras porttitor tellus turpis, eu bibendum massa sagittis nec. Donec sed nibh neque. Suspendisse at neque ac risus consequat cursus. Praesent sollicitudin eu lectus eu placerat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus arcu sapien, euismod ac placerat quis, vestibulum vel sapien. Cras purus ante, ullamcorper sit amet sodales ornare, venenatis quis risus. Ut rutrum vitae ex in vulputate. Sed vehicula massa vel nulla feugiat finibus. Sed ut posuere arcu.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
        <img class="exni" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2b8I_zX4FGxIZ8pchP9cvKf58E2ef8qmdB1EnQOVdPP4Y-dSf3XkEYLwj7vcGE5W6XVyxRZrLu6EDJqvQ1sJHWZMJiu6J8WfjUXWoNaRual_kUJaX3pKgYoezfKRTDBw6gFhHm2bfOVvVWfj92_CVi9XMpEF_c8fxThyk-Kv3nsiYEpp0s_QSHmE5N8LmrRlaFQe4xaCOqtULajJKSVjjpRXnQjaTNnH2GvxiCMq6bhmjXqgIi-U9gSQ9lM_fBB1tT-FSuwt5ftpI3WLaXIArWJ6kBELJy_qtlQR7yyqrKr91jOeCF0ap7p5iuLT999qg-6BxaEdyTfG3eia2wIK-6JUZBtSUClqF4FUcRYRqZWXX7ieaLT7e4LNK0a_nFjAx9NQdIQC7x7uGPmEx8ZvxPXPiaPK6DbhIw4y1TdPpkskcU0oLFpZjHmdZnWi4wnjPZp2dZCYa0MZ-3xnjvm21aDnF-n-JeDPYJR-8a_XZQ_R-PeoeWTU08TM7cWvoyeXWOXHWotAbVA3MRpJl2h21KgSsxN-mqT3bSuRLXqgiazqb0ubQOz4_S_N9pW3Ex3pxbhAVRZKF3H_FgcJiKaUO089-P00_qA29RK86nRHEg=w1001-h750-no" alt="">
        <p>Aliquam blandit dolor nunc, ut consectetur augue egestas eget. Maecenas tempus erat nec orci sagittis faucibus. Nulla id urna id ex imperdiet ultrices. Nullam vitae ornare turpis. Aenean dignissim odio ac euismod lacinia. Donec in fermentum nisi. Sed enim enim, vehicula vel posuere ut, ultrices quis urna. Aliquam ac ultrices neque. Aenean ultricies arcu lacinia, posuere turpis vitae, ornare orci. Donec at ante quam. Donec et facilisis felis. Morbi vestibulum condimentum est ac tincidunt.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
        <img class="exni" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2b8I_zX4FGxIZ8pchP9cvKf58E2ef8qmdB1EnQOVdPP4Y-dSf3XkEYLwj7vcGE5W6XVyxRZrLu6EDJqvQ1sJHWZMJiu6J8WfjUXWoNaRual_kUJaX3pKgYoezfKRTDBw6gFhHm2bfOVvVWfj92_CVi9XMpEF_c8fxThyk-Kv3nsiYEpp0s_QSHmE5N8LmrRlaFQe4xaCOqtULajJKSVjjpRXnQjaTNnH2GvxiCMq6bhmjXqgIi-U9gSQ9lM_fBB1tT-FSuwt5ftpI3WLaXIArWJ6kBELJy_qtlQR7yyqrKr91jOeCF0ap7p5iuLT999qg-6BxaEdyTfG3eia2wIK-6JUZBtSUClqF4FUcRYRqZWXX7ieaLT7e4LNK0a_nFjAx9NQdIQC7x7uGPmEx8ZvxPXPiaPK6DbhIw4y1TdPpkskcU0oLFpZjHmdZnWi4wnjPZp2dZCYa0MZ-3xnjvm21aDnF-n-JeDPYJR-8a_XZQ_R-PeoeWTU08TM7cWvoyeXWOXHWotAbVA3MRpJl2h21KgSsxN-mqT3bSuRLXqgiazqb0ubQOz4_S_N9pW3Ex3pxbhAVRZKF3H_FgcJiKaUO089-P00_qA29RK86nRHEg=w1001-h750-no" alt="">
        <p>In tincidunt eu metus quis volutpat. Curabitur semper ex ac elit fermentum, nec viverra neque hendrerit. Nulla aliquam vulputate odio ut posuere. Donec justo odio, blandit ut interdum id, scelerisque ac orci. Vivamus vel faucibus massa. Donec cursus nulla sed mauris fermentum porttitor. Vestibulum fringilla consequat sapien sed tincidunt. Etiam tincidunt rutrum turpis, eu porttitor libero venenatis nec. Duis placerat fringilla ultrices. Donec ac diam eget velit cursus congue eleifend at ex. Morbi sollicitudin lobortis lacinia.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
        <img class="exni" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2b8I_zX4FGxIZ8pchP9cvKf58E2ef8qmdB1EnQOVdPP4Y-dSf3XkEYLwj7vcGE5W6XVyxRZrLu6EDJqvQ1sJHWZMJiu6J8WfjUXWoNaRual_kUJaX3pKgYoezfKRTDBw6gFhHm2bfOVvVWfj92_CVi9XMpEF_c8fxThyk-Kv3nsiYEpp0s_QSHmE5N8LmrRlaFQe4xaCOqtULajJKSVjjpRXnQjaTNnH2GvxiCMq6bhmjXqgIi-U9gSQ9lM_fBB1tT-FSuwt5ftpI3WLaXIArWJ6kBELJy_qtlQR7yyqrKr91jOeCF0ap7p5iuLT999qg-6BxaEdyTfG3eia2wIK-6JUZBtSUClqF4FUcRYRqZWXX7ieaLT7e4LNK0a_nFjAx9NQdIQC7x7uGPmEx8ZvxPXPiaPK6DbhIw4y1TdPpkskcU0oLFpZjHmdZnWi4wnjPZp2dZCYa0MZ-3xnjvm21aDnF-n-JeDPYJR-8a_XZQ_R-PeoeWTU08TM7cWvoyeXWOXHWotAbVA3MRpJl2h21KgSsxN-mqT3bSuRLXqgiazqb0ubQOz4_S_N9pW3Ex3pxbhAVRZKF3H_FgcJiKaUO089-P00_qA29RK86nRHEg=w1001-h750-no" alt="">
        <p>Morbi id sapien ipsum. Praesent ullamcorper neque facilisis mauris vulputate tempus. In posuere ac ante sed imperdiet. Proin ante dui, bibendum ac lectus vitae, vestibulum elementum mi. Ut id risus ex. Phasellus porta velit dolor, ut consectetur libero suscipit sed. Aliquam ultrices risus sed dolor maximus mattis. Duis porta posuere hendrerit. Donec gravida laoreet magna at auctor. Suspendisse potenti.<br>Nam sed rhoncus ipsum. Suspendisse nec lectus purus. Phasellus interdum congue velit, eu hendrerit leo. Nulla eget lorem id magna hendrerit maximus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum non interdum nibh. Mauris varius lectus augue, ac efficitur elit pellentesque dictum. Donec sed lorem vel elit scelerisque auctor. Cras ut leo mollis, iaculis lorem at, aliquam ex. Mauris fermentum leo eget nisl porta semper. Nullam vitae dolor sit amet est viverra vestibulum. Praesent efficitur nisl turpis, quis dictum urna ullamcorper quis. Maecenas in aliquet nunc. Donec aliquam consectetur nisl, eget scelerisque libero varius vel. Duis porttitor nibh quis pulvinar gravida.</p>
    </div>
    
    <!-- 
        IMG RESIZER
     -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('.exni').height($('.exni').width());
                $(window).resize(function(){
                    $('.exni').height($('.exni').width());
                });
            });
        </script>
</section>

<!-- 
    TITLE TRIGGER
 -->

<script type="text/javascript">
        
        /* elements */
        
        var /*$introducion = $("#introducion"),*/
        $photo = $("#photo"),
        $projects = $("#projects"),
        $news = $("#news"),
        
        /* elements positions */
        
        /*$introducionPos = $introducion.offset().tot,*/
        $photoPos = $photo.offset().tot,
        $projectsPos = $projects.offset().tot,
        $newsPos = $news.offset().tot,
        
        /* window heignt */
        
        $winHeight = $(window).height(),
         
        /* distances to elements */
        
        /*$scrollToIntroducion = $introducionPos - $winHeight,*/
        $scrollToPhoto = $photoPos - $winHeight,
        $scrollToProjects = $projectsPos - $winHeight,
        $scrollToNews = $newsPos - $winHeight;
        
        /* checking */
        
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var $winScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
            /*if($winScrollTop > $scrollToIntroducion){
                $("#title").text("Introducion");
            }*/
            if($winScrollTop > $scrollToPhoto){
                $("#title").text("Galery");
            }
            else if($winScrollTop > $scrollToProjects){
                $("#title").text("Projects");
            }
            else if($winScrollTop > $scrollToNews){
                $("#title").text("News");
            }
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @air извиняюсь, не видел того вопроса, да и ответ там, на мой взгляд, немного замысловатый, ведь мне горизонтальный скролл не нужен. Что-же касается моего вопроса, то тут Kirill Korushkin хороший ответ дал, даже, на мой взгляд, менее костыльный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $fx_height = $('.fx-height'), 
    wh = $(window).height(),
    step = 100, // отвечает за нижнюю границу диапазона, в котором должен оказаться элемент своей верхней левой точкой (offset), что бы передался его контент (в данном случае значение id)
                // данное значение не должно быть больше высоты блока из набора $fx_height
$title = $('#title');

$(document).scroll(function() {
    $fx_height.each(function() {
        if(($(this).offset().top - $(document).scrollTop()) > 0 && ($(this).offset().top - $(document).scrollTop()) < step) {
            $title.html('now is on view: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
        }
    })
    
})

$(document).trigger('scroll');
```

```css
#title{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.fx-height{height:400px}
#introducion{background-color:lightgreen}
#gallery{background-color:lightblue}
#projects{background-color:lightyellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="title">now on view</h1>
<div id="blocks">
    <div id="introducion" class="fx-height">introducion block</div>
    <div id="gallery" class="fx-height">gallery block</div>
    <div id="projects" class="fx-height">projects block</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Всё достаточно работает, но вот '#introducion' не хочет меняться, при загрузке страницы '#title' не меняется, а если прокрутить вниз и снова вверх вернуться, то '#title' остаётся now on view: photo. Если что, каждый блок имеент высоту не менее 100vh

Comment: @Дмитрий Шишков там есть переменная step, она отвечает за нижнюю границу диапазона, в котором должен оказаться элемент своей верхней левой точкой (offset), что бы передался его контент (в данном случае значение id). Диапазон считается от верхней точки экрана и до step (от 0 вниз, в px)

Comment: Но какое значение подставлять, если первый блок находится в смаом начале страницы?

Comment: @Дмитрий Шишков добавил пояснение в ответ

Answer (score 2):

Уберите внутреннюю обертку

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  ...
});
```

вокруг `if-else`ов. Код **уже** находится в обработчике события `scroll`

*Update*

> Чего-то не понял

Ваш код выглядит так:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  ...
  $(window).scroll(function(){
  ...
  });
});
```

Что это делает:

- сначала внешний `$(window).scroll(function(){` навешивает обработчик на событие `scroll`,
- потом на каждое событие `scroll` этот внешний обработчик добавляет еще один обработчик - код внутри внутреннего `$(window).scroll(function(){` (и еще, и еще, и еще).

*Update*

> даже после того, как убрал, ничего не происходит

Вы же не показали Вашу разметку. Может у Вас логика `if-else` неправильная.

*Update*

Разверните условия в `if-else` от нижнего элемента к верхнему.

Comment: Чего-то не понял, как это так, "уже находится"?

Comment: И даже после того, как убрал, ничего не происходит

Comment: Действительно, $(window).scroll(function(){ уже есть, но это так и не решило проблемы

Comment: @ДмитрийШишков см. последний *Update* в ответе

Comment: Всё-равно ничего не работает, ладно, внизу уже есть решение